# Mixing different types of columns in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Can I mix different columns (col-xs-*, col-sm-* etc) in my layout?

For example, I have:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
   ...
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
   ...
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
   ...
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
   ...
</div>
```

and more many col-xs columns.

But now for example, I want to change first column from full width to half in tablets and monitors, so I added "col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3" and remove "col-xs-12" because "col-sm-6" means "col-xs-12":

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
   ...
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
   ...
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
   ...
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
   ...
</div>
```

And it works, **but this is correct with bootstrap grid system and standards?**

Or Maybe I have to add "col-sm-*" to others? :

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
   ...
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
   ...
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
   ...
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
   ...
</div>
```

Or maybe I have to keep "col-xs-12"?

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
   ...
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
   ...
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
   ...
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
   ...
</div>
```

Or maybe I have to keep "col-xs-12" and add "col-sm-*" to others to have identical types in all divs?

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
   ...
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
   ...
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
   ...
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
   ...
</div>
```

Which versions is correct? How do I properly mix different types of columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the other answers explain what overrides what, but to answer your question about what you have to have, the default is 100% width. So if you only specify:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  ...
</div>
```

then when you get smaller than 768px it will go from 50% (6 columns) to 100 (12 columns)

Answer (score 3):

Bigger sizes override smaller sizes (e.g. `col-sm` will override `col-xs` unless the screen is smaller than `col-sm`). Personally I always add a `col-xs` and I only add the bigger sizes when I need them.

Example:

```
<!-- full width on phones and half on anything bigger -->
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: In your example, isn't the `col-xs-12` redundant?

Answer (score 2):

This information is all found in Bootstrap's Documentation. It is perfectly fine to add multiple `col-*-*` classes to a `<div>` element:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
...
</div>
```

Is a perfectly viable class structure, that renders different column sizes depending on the current size of the viewport. If xs, it would be a full-width column. Small is half, medium is a 3rd and large is a 4th (based on a 12 column layout.)

If you need more information, take a look here:

[Bootstrap Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Answer (score 1):

Column sizing will default with the smallest size first (xs) with subsequent classes overriding the original size.

For example:

```
<div class="col-xs-12"></div>
```

Will appear as with 100% width on all browsers.

The following will appear as 100% on mobile browsers and 50% on tablets and up.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"></div>
```